# Sql Server date format should be like " Oct 17, 2014 10:14 PM"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to display date as **"Oct 10, 2014 1:06 PM"**

My SQL query is

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(char(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100), 18,0, ' ')
```

and it is displaying like

**"Oct 10 2014  1:06 PM"**

Comment: can you try i posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the syntax for stuff. Why don't you just add another stuff ?

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(char(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100), 18,0, ' '), 7,0, ',')
```

Comment: date for length may be vary on while date between 1-9.

Comment: @NareshPansuriya, no the length of the date is always the same. Try this: SELECT STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(char(19), cast('2014-10-09' as date), 100), 18,0, ' '), 7,0, ',')

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(char(13),GETDATE(),107)+CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100)


Output
Oct 10, 2014 1:24PM
```

Comment: he need to space before AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible directly in sqlserver. you just need to use one more stuff function like

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(CHAR(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100), 18, 0, ' '), 7, 0, ',')
```

Comment: ohh. duplicate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below format

```
select convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 107) + ' ' + REVERSE(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(char(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100)), 0, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(CONVERT(char(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 100)))),3,0,' '))
```

Comment: this is a bit overkill, way to complicated. When you know the length of an expression you should always use char(X). When using varchar, you should always specify the length as in varchar(X)